# Using Callback or Observer to add attributes to associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, observer-pattern

I would like after saving in one model to create a few lists in my list model.

So I can get that to work for one list in the controller (I know bad) like this:

```
     @move.save
     @list = List.new(:name => 'This is a List', :move_id => @move.id)
     @list.save
```

I need to move that to the model or an observer and then be able to add several different lists with that one action. I am not sure how to do this. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be in an observer, as I believe a callback should only make changes to the object it is a part of, whereas an observer can interact with other models.

Comment: Thanks I will put it in an observer... any ideas on adding multiples lists?